# Clutch biting at high revs when pressed down

Tags: clutch, renault, clio

I have a 2004 Renaultsport Clio 182. I was toying with it yesterday and had the car in first gear, clutch flat to the floor, and I revved the car. At around 6000 rpm I felt the clutch bite and the car pull forwards slightly.

What is the cause of this?

Comment: Friction drag as the gap is only small and the fluid (air) between the plates can transmit power if the speed is sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Friction drag as the gap is only small and the fluid (air) between the plates can transmit power if the speed is sufficient.

Comment: Is this a sign of clutch deterioration?

Comment: No - as the clutch plate wears the gap gets bigger...